# Eclipse CORBA plugin howto

Tags: eclipse, plugins, corba

I'm new to CORBA and I need to learn how to use it with C++.
I see that there is a CORBA plugin for Eclipse, is there some tutorial on how to use this plugin? Are there better ways to use CORBA with Eclipse? Or any other way without Eclipse ;-)
Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: @Pedro What support do you expect?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for some tutorial on how to use CORBA plugin for Eclipse, some sample code. Or that someone tells me: "forget Eclipse and its CORBA plugin, use this instead..."
I'm using Fedora 12 and Eclipse 3.5.1.

Comment: After playing around with the plugin I see that is only generates code for Java, not C++... so it is not what I want...

Answer (score 1):

There should be a CORBA IDL 'compiler' or 'translator', that creates C++ code from CORBA's IDL, after that, all you have to do is use the code created by the CORBA IDL to C++ translator in order to communicate your distributed software components.

There are several implementations of these 'translators' here: http://patriot.net/~tvalesky/freecorba.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was done on my birthday day ;-) I'm not doing CORBA any more but I'll take a look at your page.